# Is it correct to say "not that I have known"?

Tags: grammaticality

Consider:

> A: Do you know this guy?
>
> B: Not that I have known.

Is **"Not that I have known"** correct? The other **"not that I know of"** seems more suitable to me but is the first one grammatically correct?

Comment: You want to say he has changed and he is not the previous person who you knew

Comment: lol, NO. just tell is this expression right? if something does not know, can he say "Not that I have known"

Comment: Right or Wrong depends on the context. Not {the person} that I have known is very different from I don't know him.

Comment: So, it's not right? the guy A just asked a question in a comment, do you know the guy B? and someone ( who claims to be an English writer) Comments : "Not that I have known" I wanna point out him, if he is wrong. and how he is wrong?

Comment: I am not sure, It is not grammatically wrong, lets wait for the native :)

Comment: yes sure, lets find out  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Did your dog ever dig up your neighbor's garden?
>   -- Not that I am aware of.
>   -- Not as far as I know.
>   -- Not that I know of.
>
> Do you know this man?
>   --No, I do not.

We use "Not that I know of" and its variants to say that we have no knowledge of something. It is not an outright denial but a profession of *ignorance*

> Is there an ATM on this block?
>   --Not that I know of.

or a statement that we have no such recollection :

> Have you seen this man before?
>   -- Not that I am aware of.

We can be ignorant about the ATM, and we may fail to recall whether we have *seen* a person before, but we cannot profess ignorance about that with which we are acquainted; nor can we claim not to remember persons with whom we are familiar. Not unless we have amnesia. We are either acquainted with something or someone, or not. We can  profess ignorance about a fact but we cannot profess ignorance about our knowledge.

**Do you know him? Are you acquainted with him? Do you know who he is?**

These questions want a "yes/no" answer.

Comment: Thanks. You mean to say that "Not that I have known" is incorrect?

Comment: I was adding commentary as you were typing.

Comment: Nice commentary, but pardon me, I'm still not sure if "Not that I HAVE KNOWN" is correct or incorrect.

Comment: I have never heard that phrase used, and it gets no hits on Google Ngram, so I believe it to be unidiomatic. But if there is a dialect in which it is used, I would suppose it to be analogous to the "Not that I ..." variants mentioned in my answer. So the precise question to which that phrase is the answer is very important to know.

Comment: The phrase might be used in answer to a question whether one has *done* something.  *When backing your car out of the garage, have you ever driven over your neighbor's petunias? -- Not that I've known.*

Comment: Sohail: Just because something is "not incorrect" or "not ungrammatical" doesn't mean it will sound natural or idiomatic. I can't think of a reason that _"Not that I have known"_ should be deemed "incorrect," but I think I'd be much more likely to say (or hear) something more along the lines of: _Not that I can remember._ But that doesn't make the other version "wrong."